# Pymongo specify unique constraint for certain keys

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, pymongo

I want to create 3 indexes in my collection one with unique constrain et the other without unique. To create multiple indexes I do this :

```
collection.create_index(
   [("key1", pymongo.DESCENDING), 
   ("key2", pymongo.DESCENDING), 
   ("key3", pymongo.DESCENDING)], 
   unique=True
)
```

But all my indexes will be unique. How can I do to set just the key1 unique ? Does the only solution is to repeat the index creation twice ? Or I miss something ?

```
collection.create_index(
   [("key1", pymongo.DESCENDING)],
   unique=True
)

collection.create_index(
   [("key2", pymongo.DESCENDING),
   ("key3", pymongo.DESCENDING)]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code example creates a single [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/) over all three fields.

If you want to separately index the three columns, you need to make a separate `create_index` call for each:

```
collection.create_index(
   [("key1", pymongo.DESCENDING)],
   unique=True
)

collection.create_index(
   [("key2", pymongo.DESCENDING)]
)

collection.create_index(
   [("key3", pymongo.DESCENDING)]
)
```

Comment: Oh yeah you right. I didn't know compound index. Thank you ! But  I don't understand in which case it can be useful to use that.